# SSIS- OleDb Fast Load vs. Bulk Insert Task

Tags: ssis, oledb, bulkinsert

I have done research including threads on this forum but cant seem to find an answer.

I am loading text files with 40 columns.  No transformation at this time.  There are 8 files ~25MB with a total of 1,400,000 rows.  Using Bulk Insert task the load completes in 3 minutes.  Using OleDb destination and flat file input connection manager the load completes in 30 minutes.

From all I have read, SSIS should be using Bulk Inserts behind the OleDb connection.  If so, why is there such a dramatic difference?  I must be doing something wrong, any ideas?

Using all defaults for the connection.  Table or View fast load.  Blank rows per batch and max commit size 2,147,483,674.  I am using Sql2016 but have had similar results testing with Sql2014.

Comment: Double click the line between the flat file source and the OLE DB Destination - what data types and lengths are listed in the Metadata tab?

Comment: I have 44 dt_str fields.  I had set the width to 8000 to ensure no truncation.  Thanks for asking me to look into this.  Combined with the answer from Adhiraj it us running in 45 seconds now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not setting up the properties of Data Flow Task such as DefaultBufferSize and DefaultBufferMaxRows.