# Best Tuning steps for SSIS packages with Execute SQL Tasks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

What necessary tuning I can do in ssis level,if all of the functionality have been
implemented using the Execute SQL task stored procedures.
All most all tables being used are already indexed.Please suggest some useful
ssis tuning tips for such kind of packages.Do I have to implement all these 
execute sql tasks to Data flow task!?

Comment: My guess is the procedures are where you need to focus. And just saying the tables are indexed does NOT mean they are indexed correctly for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, no.  Data flow tasks, in my opinion, are mostly useful when moving data between two sources or to do complex logic that you would rather use a c# script and not use the .Net CLR in SQL Server to perform that script.

If the source and destination are on the same instance I have never seen an occasion where SSIS data flow tasks can out-perform a properly built stored procedure.

Because you are using execute sql tasks, there is no SSIS performance tuning.  All that SSIS is doing is launching something to be done by SQL Server.

I would focus on your stored procedures, look into the execution plans and read up on SQL Server Query Performance Tuning.  It could range from a very simple index recommended when you look at the execution plan, moderate effort using Query Analyzer tool or very complex. It depends on your data and queries.

Comment: This is very useful

Comment: There is one data flow task.How to calculate the max insert commit size and other  properties such buffer sizes .Is it based on the number of rows coming from source multiplied by each column length!?

Comment: I have found that the default values are best.  Make sure Table or View - Fast Load is selected so that bulk operations will be performed.  Here is a good article on the topic. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/using-sql-server-integration-services-to-bulk-load-data/   One thing I dont see mentioned often is the source connection manager advanced properties.  Here is a link to a question I asked on the topic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727130/ssis-oledb-fast-load-vs-bulk-insert-task